# AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 macro not found

Tags: linux, c++11, macros, autoconf, building

Try to install [Sigrok under Linux](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Linux).
Step: **libsigrok** installing. When I try
*./autogen.sh*
I get a warning "**AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 macro not found**".
As far as I see, it crashes my attempt to make PulseView package later (*libsigrokxx>=0.3.0 not found*).
I checked *autoconf* and *autoconf-archive* with Synaptic - it's ok. Don't know what to do next. No experience in building programs.
Thanks!

Comment: The warning says "SRDCXX", not "STDCXX", meaning you simply have a typo.

Comment: Excuses! It's my fault. The warning says

AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 (as in the header I wrote)

Comment: Then presumably the autoconf-archive package of your distro is too old.

Comment: Another possibility is that your distro installs autoconf-archive in such a way that it does not get picked up by default, and additional `-I` options are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

2 @nos: I used a Synaptic to check the state of autoconf and autoconf-archive. It says the versions are latest.

2 hvd: Do I need to reinstall autoconf-archive? Or where have I to use this additional -I option?

Comment: I don't know how your distro packages autoconf-archive. You probably don't need to reinstall it. If `-I` options are needed, it'll be in the `aclocal` command called by `autogen.sh`, but the details depend on your distro.

Comment: @drvlas Synaptic will say it's the latest _for your linux distro_ . There might be a newer version of your particular linux distro, or your linux distro might not contain the newest upstream autoconf-archive package. I suggest you try an official release of libsigrok, http://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads, where the ./configure script is already present.

Comment: I think you are right about "the latest version" of autoconf-archive. It may be not latest... 
And, though I can use the official release of all packets (as you propose), I'll try to remove and re-install autoconf-archive. Just to learn more. 
The results will be reported here.
Thanks!

Comment: My result is zero. And the deadline coming. So I took a Saleae package to work with my Logic Analizer clone and left the Pulseview for better times.

Happy New Year, folks! And thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Mostly likely your autoconf-archive package does not contain this macro.  My Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS system had the same problem.

It's possible to install this macro manually with the following steps:

Go [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html) and download the macro to somewhere.

Then copy this macro into the '/usr/share/aclocal' directory.  Make sure it's named 'ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4'.  When I downloaded it I ended up with a 'm4-' pre-pended on the filename.

Make sure the macro is world readable and things should be go to go.

This fixed things for me.

Comment: Dropped the topic that time. I managed to run my Saleae logic analyzer under Linux - and this resolved my problem. So far... But Sigrok is interesting. So - thanks a lot for your answer. I'll check it.

Comment: Well, I installed libsigrok and PulseView. If I'd knew what can I do with it... Thank you for a right answer, Richard!

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install autoconf-archive` was the solution for me.

If you are the author of a package don't forget to rebuild it with `autoreconf --install --force` before `configure`, `make`...